# How can i change 'post_modify' with a query?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm sorry for my english. I'm trying to change the value of post_modified columns with a query like that:

```
$wpdb->query( "UPDATE `$wpdb->posts` SET `post_modified` = ".$data_modifica_post."  WHERE ID = ".$iddelpostdaverificare."");
```

but it doesn't work.

Is possible to change manually post_modified (and post_modified_gmt) or it only change automatically with an update of the post from the back-end?

Comment: That should work.  I assume you checked your variables are set as you expect.  You might need quotes around the date (eg `= '".$data_modifica_post."'` - I think the generated query should be something like `= '2014-08-31' WHERE`, not `= 2014-08-31 WHERE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your date in a pair of single quotes. 
Also, you need to make sure that $wpdb is using the global $wpdb object.
In addition, you should make sure that:

- $iddelpostdaverificare contains the right ID
- $data_modifica_post is a valid date, like 2014-10-30 or 2014-10-30 23:59:59

I'm sending you the updated code that contains the above updates - it has been tested and works properly.

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( "UPDATE `$wpdb->posts` SET `post_modified` = '" . $data_modifica_post . "'  WHERE ID = " . $iddelpostdaverificare);
```

Comment: IT WORKS!!!!!! THANKS THANKS THANKS A LOT!!!! The error was really stupid because i tried the query without single quote or thit single quaote but like this ` . The right one is ' . Really thanks to you and also @hobo